# Database Record created_at Time Randomly Changes

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) based on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/).

I'm using a server with Debian, PHP7, PHP-FPM and APCu.

I have NTP installed and server time set to UTC.

In `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` I have set `date.timezone = "UTC"`.

---

I have a gallery where you can upload a file.

It saves a record to the database and sets the time uploaded to the `created_at` column.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time());

# Save Database Record
$image = new Gallery();
$image->title = $title;
$image->created_at = $date;
$image->save();
```

---

The gallery is arranged by latest image first, using `created_at` date/time.

Several times now after uploading, the time on the record has been set many hours back.

This makes the gallery images display all out of order.

OctoberCMS database viewer:

[image: database created_at time]

---

When I run `date` in the terminal, it returns `15:39:24`, 3:39 **PM**.

What could be causing the time to change? And why 3 different conflicting times?

Comment: Have you tried using Carbon instead of `date()`?

Comment: @GiamPy I may have solved it, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the date format. It should be `Y-m-d H:i:s` instead of `Y-m-d h:i:s`

The small `h` is for 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
and the capital `H` is for 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

I may have solved it, I've changed `h:i:s` to `H:i:s`.

I think it was saving the record as 12 hour format, then Laravel was displaying that back as 24 hour format.

October's database viewer always shows time as 12 hour format, so I didn't catch it.

I'll see after a few hours if that cleared it up.